# How to make a Roblox FPS Unlocker?

Tags: c#

The title basically says it all but how how would you go about making a c# code to unlock Roblox FPS cap?

- I've tried looking online but couldn't find anything myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has already made a FPS Unlocker for this game.

https://github.com/axstin/rbxfpsunlocker/releases

It is written in C++. The code is open-source so you could study it to see how it works.